# PhoneGap with BlackBerry gap_poll error

Tags: javascript, blackberry, cordova, blackberry-webworks

When I start my application, I keep getting alerts popups that are related to PhoneGap: gap_callbackServer, gap_poll, getToken, etc...

And then finally the "gap_poll" error keeps appearing, and whether you press 'OK' or 'Cancel', it keep going indefinitely.

If I exclude "phonegap.js" from my pages, everything goes fine, except that I can't use PhoneGap abilities. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

having the same error but I  just seem to have got past it now by making sure I was using the blackberry version of the phonegap.js file, - i had earlier just copied my android  project which of course had the android version.   The different platforms have different .js files.

Comment: Is there a way I can include all versions of phonegap.js so the application can compile on all devices ?